# Binding insert query with multiple values in Laravel issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I followed the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#running-queries)

where i have an insert statement:

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle']);
```

I have an insert query with multiple values, so I tried the following:

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle'], (?, ?)', [2, 'Jimmy'], (?, ?)', [3, 'John']);
```

and

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle'], [2, 'Jimmy'], , [3, 'John']);
```

None of them are working :(

What am i doing wrong ? thx

Comment: You have a model of Users? Also what error are you getting?

Comment: This is the error message: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your Ma  
  riaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query looks fine and it works for me. But if you want to avoid this kind of problem you should use [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#inserts):

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['name' => 'Dayle'],
    ['name' => 'John'],
]);
```

Or [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent):

```
User::create([
    ['name' => 'Dayle'],
    ['name' => 'John'],
]);
```

If for some reason you want to use `DB::insert()`, this works:

```
DB::insert('insert into users (name) values ("Dayle"), ("Jimmy")');
```

And using bindings:

```
DB::insert('insert into users (name) values (?), (?)', ['Dayle', 'Jimmy'])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it, in my way? I know that eloquent is a possible solution. but that is not what i asked. thx :)

Comment: @Chester I've just realised first one from your question worked for you, but you want to insert multiple rows at one time. I've updated my answer and the code is working, but I really recommend you to use Query Builder at least.

Comment: and using bindings :D  with "? ? ? "

Comment: @Chester ok I"ve dived into the source code and found the way. Please check an updated answer.

Comment: one more thing how can i memorize in one variable those arrays [1, 'test'] [2, 'test2'] [3, 'test3']. Because in the end I need smth like this: DB::insert($query, $myarrays)   ?

Comment: `DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?), (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle', 2, 'Jimmy'])`